# Trying to create a React component that returns a clicked on name & email

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I've been trying to avoid this, but I've been going over this for 72 hours and I just need help, so here it is:

I am trying to create a component that will return the name and email of the person that's clicked on. I need the name to display in the contact form "Your email will be sent to {person that's been clicked on}" and the email to be the source for where the email is sent securely. This is the code that I currently have (it might be totally wrong):

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby';

export default function WhoToEmail({ personToEmail }) {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      members: allSanityBoardMembers {
        nodes {
          name
          email
          id
        }
      }
      committees: allSanityCommittees {
        nodes {
          id
          email
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const members = data.members.nodes;
  const name = members.map((names) => names.name);
  const email = members.map((emails) => emails.email);
  const id = members.map((ids) => ids.id);

  function whichOne(keyId) {
    id.forEach((item, index) => {
      if (item === keyId) {
        return [name[index], email[index]];
      }
      return console.log('Unknown Member');
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {!whichOne(id) ? (
        ' '
      ) : (
        <div key={id}>Your email will be sent to {name}</div>
      )}

      <div className="hide">email is output</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I call the component in page with `<WhoToEmail personToEmail={pageContext.name} />`, which displays fine - I know that it's the component I'm getting wrong. Help is appreciated.

Comment: If you already have `personToEmail` why are you making the query and filtering data and such?

Comment: Thanks for responding @TJ. I don't follow what you mean (I wouldn't be terribly shocked to find I've overthought this).

Comment: `WhoToEmail({ personToEmail })` here it looks like you already know whom to email. So what's all the filtering about?

Comment: I need the function to return only the relevant name to display and email to send to, so that I'm not getting an array `onClick`. You're saying that I can just have an empty function component?